# USB Headset test in KDE works but no sound from applications

Tags: audio, fedora, kde, pulse-audio

My G35 appears in all the audio settings files. I can click the test buttons and hear sound. I can also right click on the kmix speaker icon, Select Master Channel and choose the headset. This gives me a volume control for it that works for the test sounds. Applications that make sounds appear in playback streams, but I don't hear anything from them. I've tried restarting, killing `pulseaudio -k` (which auto restarts). Nothing seems to work. What can I try?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I installed `pavucontrol`, in which I could click the "Fallback" button for the headset in the "Output Devices" tab. This also has the very useful interface which shows where audio is being sent (KDE4 used to do this. those were the days). I also disabled all other devices as occasionally they would be used instead. Now everything works, after restarting the apps with audio.

[image]

This sometimes fails after a reboot. `killall pulseaudio` and restarting it seems to make the headset get detected properly in phonon and then it shows in `pavucontrol` to set as "fallback".

Finally, installing `phonon-backend-vlc` was necessary to fix `amarok`. `gstreamer` simply didn't work (I suspect a missing codec).

Comment: the "fallback" and "disable device" options on pavucontrol, and the line that displays the output volume per device, are all great.  Turns out it was my headphones that were broken.  but pavucontrol helped me work that out.